# Updating Leaflet label from form in popup

Tags: leaflet, popup

I have a Leaflet map with markers that originate from two places: Stored coordinates in a database, retrieved as JSON and loaded to a GeoJSON object. The other is markers created from leaflet.Draw plugin.

With the database stored coordinates,  I use pointToLayer to make them show up as circlemarkers, and associate a markerID property to them so I can track their database ID for future editing and Ajax calls to the server:

```
    //load markers from database
    $.getJSON("markers", function(data){
    //create markers
    var markers = L.geoJson(data, {
        //add each marker to drawnItems layer so they are editable with the draw plugin
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, markerOptions);
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.markerId = feature.properties.id; //add ID to properties to reference later
            layer.name=feature.properties.name;
            attachPopup(layer);
            layer.bindTooltip(layer.name, {permanent: true, direction: 'right', className: 'custom'});
            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        }
    });
});
```

In the attachPopup() logic, I have a popup form template that I attach to each marker to show form inputs with the name of the marker and some other information. I have a 'save' button on that popup. In the script I have a delegated listener for the '.save' being clicked and I fire off an update to the database:

```
$('body').on('click', '.save', function(){
        //get form data
        const form = document.querySelector('form');
        var data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
        //send to server via ajax call (removed for brevity)
    });
```

The problem: On success from the Ajax database call - how do I update the layer.name property of the circlemarker whose name I am editing? I cannot figure out how to do this without refreshing the page/map and refetching and redrawing all the markers. I want the edited name to show in the popup form AND on the tooltip label. I am trying to figure out how to find that particular marker by its markerID that I assigned so I can update its properties.

A related question is this: When I add a marker using leaflet.Draw I immediately save it to the database and then display the popup form for further editing. When the form is submitted by clicking the save button - how do I set the layer.name for the marker?

EDIT: attachPopup() code added

```
function attachPopup(layer)
{
    var popupContent ='<form role="form" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">'+
      '<div class="form-group">'+
          '<label class="control-label"><strong>Marker Type: </strong></label>'+
          '<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">'+
            '<option value="stand">Type 1</option>'+
            '<option value="parking">Type 2</option>'+
            '<option value="Other">Other</option>'+
          '</select>'+ 
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="form-group">'+
          '<label class="control-label"><strong>Name: </strong></label>'+
          '<textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="descrip" name="descript">'+layer.name+'</textarea>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="Unique_id" name="unique_id" value="'+layer._leaflet_id+'" />'+
      '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="id" name="id" value="'+layer.markerId+'" />'+
      '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="lat" name="lat" value="'+layer.getLatLng().lat+'" />'+
      '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="lng" name="lng" value="'+layer.getLatLng().lng+'" />'+
      '<div class="form-group">'+
        '<div style="text-align:center;" class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2"><button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button></div>'+
        '<div style="text-align:center;" class="col-xs-4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save">Save</button></div>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</form>';
    
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {
        keepInView: true,
        closeButton: true,
        minWidth: 180
    }).openPopup();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Leaflet each member of a group layer (marker is member of GeoJSON group layer) gets internal id, which can be retrieved with `.getLayerId` method. This id can later be used to retrieve desired member (marker) with the `.getLayer` method.

When you construct your popup with `attachPopup(layer)`, you can retrieve marker layer id with

```
var layerId = markers.getLayerId(layer);
```

You can save this id somewhere in your popup object and later use it to retrieve desired marker and change it's `name` property:

```
var marker = markers.getLayer(savedId);
marker.name = newMarkerName;
```

To use this, you can add `data-layer-id` data attribute to the form element, with the value of layer id:

```
function attachPopup(layer)
{
    var layerId = markers.getLayerId(layer);
    var popupContent ='<form role="form" id="form" data-layer-id="' + layerId + '" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">'+
.
.
.
```

Then you can retrieve value of this attribute in your click event callback:

```
$('body').on('click', '.save', function(){
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  var layerId = form.getAttribute('data-layer-id');
  var markerLayer = markers.getLayer(layerId);
  var data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
});
```

Comment: thank you. I edited OP to include the code for attachPopup()

Comment: Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: One more follow up question for you - are markers created from Leaflet.Draw plugin handled differently than markers created from geoJSON?

Comment: No, they aren't.